# GPS program works on JellyBean and KitKat but not Gingerbread

Tags: android, gps, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am have written an app to find the GPS coordinates. The program works totally fine on Android 4.3 and 4.4.2 but for some reason its not working on 2.3.4 and 2.3.6. The GPS is not even turning on. Is there something additional that needs to be done to make it compatible with older APIs? I have included the following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
```

This is the code :

```
package com.hari.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
public static Context mContext;

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public void setContext(Context mContext) {
    MainActivity.mContext = mContext;
}
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
public static float lat, lng;
public static TextView t3, t4, t5, t6;
// SMSReceiver s;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Location not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }

}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // s.onReceive(getApplicationContext(), getIntent());
    //
    // t3.setText(s.messageReceived);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

public void msg(View view) {
    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    String phoneno = "8056371433";
    String s = e1.getText().toString();
    String message, m1, m2;
    t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
    t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
    t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);
    t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text6);
    m1 = String.valueOf(lat);
    m2 = String.valueOf(lng);
    message = m1 + " " + m2;
    if (e1.getText().length() == 0)
        sendSMS(phoneno, message);
    else
        sendSMS(s, message);
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    boolean flag1 = true, flag2 = true;
    lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());
    lng = (float) (location.getLongitude());
    if (lng < 0) {
        lng = -lng;
        flag1 = false;
    }
    if (lat < 0) {
        lat = -lat;
        flag2 = false;
    }

    if (flag2)
        latituteField.setText("Latitude = " + lat + " N" + "\n");
    else
        latituteField.setText("Latitude = " + lat + " S" + "\n");

    if (flag1)
        longitudeField.setText("Longitude = " + lng + " E");
    else
        longitudeField.setText("Longitude = " + lng + " W");
    // deg = Math.abs((int) lat);
    // min = (int) ((lat - (float) deg) * 60.0);
    // sec = (int) ((((lat - (float) deg) * 60) - min) * 60);
    // if (flag2)
    // latituteField.setText("Latitude    =  " +String.valueOf(deg) + "° "
    // + String.valueOf(min) + "\' " + String.valueOf(sec) + "\""
    // + 'N'+"\n");
    // else
    // latituteField.setText("Latitude    =  " +String.valueOf(deg) + "° "
    // + String.valueOf(min) + "\' " + String.valueOf(sec) + "\""
    // + 'S'+"\n");
    // deg = Math.abs((int) lng);
    // min = (int) ((lng - (float) deg) * 60.0);
    // sec = (int) ((((lng - (float) deg) * 60) - min) * 60);
    // if (flag1)
    // longitudeField.setText("Longitude = " + String.valueOf(deg) + "° "
    // + String.valueOf(min) + "\' " + String.valueOf(sec) + "\""
    // + 'E');
    // else
    // longitudeField.setText("Longitude = " + String.valueOf(deg) + "° "
    // + String.valueOf(min) + "\' " + String.valueOf(sec) + "\""
    // + 'W');
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Those permissions look good.  Post your code?

Comment: I have posted the code..

Comment: The getLastKnownLocation in onCreate obviously won't start the GPS subsystem, but I see you are requesting location updates in onResume.  Its possible that getBestProvider is returning something that can't be used at this time-  have you tried hard coding the network or gps provider and seeing the results?  Personally I avoid getbestprovider-  an app tends to either need GPS (in which case I use it) or not (in which case I avoid it for battery usage).

Comment: actually the above code works well for phones running JellyBean and KitKat.. I am getting issues only with Gingerbread and being able to run it on Gingerbread is kind of important for my project..

Comment: Stupid question... have you made sure the location services are turned on in the Android Settings menus for your gingerbread device?

Comment: Yeah I did.. And you mind your language when you comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add requestlocationupdates() to make it work Strange that I was getting GPS coordinates without using the said function on Jellybean and KitKat. So the modified code is :

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
Location location = locationManager
.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
//start 
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,OnMapLongClickListener,OnMarkerClickListener,GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
    // Update interval in milliseconds for location services
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    // Fastest update interval in milliseconds for location services
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000;  
    // Google Play diagnostics constant
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;  
    // Speed threshold for orienting map in direction of motion (m/s) 
    private static final double SPEED_THRESH = 1;

    private static final String TAG = "Mapper";
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private double currentLat;
    private double currentLon;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng map_center;
    private int zoomOffset = 5;
    private float currentZoom;
    private float bearing;
    private float speed;
    private float acc;
    private Circle localCircle;

    private double lon;
    private double lat;
    static final int numberOptions = 10;
    String [] optionArray = new String[numberOptions];

    // Define an object that holds accuracy and frequency parameters
    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    // Set up shared preferences to persist data.  We will use it later
    // to save the current zoom level if user leaves this activity, and
    // restore it when she returns.

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
    //  map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
        //      .findFragmentById(R.id.mapme_map)).getMap();
        map=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.mapme_map)).getMap();

        if(map != null){

            // Set the initial zoom level of the map
            currentZoom = map.getMaxZoomLevel()-zoomOffset;

            // Add a click listener to the map
            map.setOnMapClickListener(this);

            // Add a long-press listener to the map
            map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

            // Add Marker click listener to the map
            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

            // Add marker info window click listener
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        /* Create new location client. The first 'this' in args is the present
         * context; the next two 'this' args indicate that this class will handle 
         * callbacks associated with connection and connection errors, respectively 
         * (see the onConnected, onDisconnected, and onConnectionError callbacks below).  
         * You cannot use the location client until the onConnected callback 
         * fires, indicating a valid connection.  At that point you can access location
         * services such as present position and location updates. 
         */

        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Set request for high accuracy
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set update interval
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set fastest update interval that we can accept
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        // Get a shared preferences
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Get a SharedPreferences editor
        prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

        // Keep screen on while this map location tracking activity is running
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    }

    // Following two methods display and handle the top bar options menu for maps
    // Save the current zoom level when going into the background
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        // Store the current map zoom level
        if(map != null){
            currentZoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
            prefsEditor.putFloat("KEY_ZOOM",currentZoom);
            prefsEditor.commit();  
        }
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG,"onPause: Zoom="+currentZoom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Restore previous zoom level (default to max zoom level if
        // no prefs stored)

        if (prefs.contains("KEY_ZOOM") && map != null){
            currentZoom = prefs.getFloat("KEY_ZOOM", map.getMaxZoomLevel());
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"onResume: Zoom="+currentZoom);

        // Keep screen on while this map location tracking activity is running
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }


    /* The following two lifecycle methods conserve resources by ensuring that
     * location services are connected when the map is visible and disconnected when
     * it is not.
     */

    // Called by system when Activity becomes visible, so connect location client.

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    // Called by system when Activity is no longer visible, so disconnect location
    // client, which invalidates it.

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        // If the client is connected, remove location updates and disconnect
        if (locationClient.isConnected()) {
            locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        }
        locationClient.disconnect();

        // Turn off the screen-always-on request
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        super.onStop();
    }
}
```